# mysql not storing microseconds in datetime but using in where condition?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have this schema

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `dt` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE='InnoDB';

INSERT INTO `test` (`dt`) VALUES ('2018-02-19 17:21:51.321343');
```

why there is no result for this query?

`select * from test where dt = '2018-02-19 17:21:51.321343';`

so I'm using datetime not datetime(6) .. the microseconds part is not stored, why is it being compared then?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bed0c3/3

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no result from your query because you are comparing a value stored in the table against a different value. They don't match, therefore the search expression is false.

The comparison of a time with no microseconds against a time with microseconds is false:

```
mysql> select '2018-02-19 17:21:51' = '2018-02-19 17:21:51.321343' as is_equal;
+----------+
| is_equal |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
```

In the same way that a comparison between *pi* and an integer is false:

```
mysql> select 3.1415927 = 3 as is_equal;
+----------+
| is_equal |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
```

You can resolve this by casting your fractional datetime value to one with no milliseconds:

```
mysql> select '2018-02-19 17:21:51' = cast('2018-02-19 17:21:51.321343' as datetime) as is_equal;
+----------+
| is_equal |
+----------+
|        1 |
+----------+
```

Casting as `datetime` is the same as casting as `datetime(0)`. That is, 0 digits of fractional seconds.

---

Re your comment.

Think of it this way: You search for a value. The value you search for isn't stored in the table. So the search fails. Isn't this logical?

Comment: Thanks, why is this needed when the `dt` column is `datetime` type already? even if queried it returns only the datetime part without mili/microseconds.

Comment: Thanks @Bill it makes sense.. I got confused by the fact the the query actually returns data if `dt` column has INDEX specified .. any idea why? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69dfe/1

Comment: Wow, I've never noticed that, but I can reproduce it. I'm not sure if that's intentional behavior.